# Replicate form logout submit functionality with javascript

Tags: ajax, forms, vue.js, openid-connect, express-session

I have a functioning logout button which successfully ends a session established using express server ExpressOIDC/express-session. The OIDC sessions and the user is redirected to the logged out view. The logout button html is shown here:

```html
<form v-if="authenticated" method="POST" action="/logout" id="auth-logout-form" v-cloak>
  <span class="user-name">{{userName}}</span>
  <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

I simply want to mimic this function in my code for inactivity logout.

First I tried a simple **$.post('logout')**. But this produces the following errors:

> > Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxxxxx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout?id_token_hint=xxxxxxxxx&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F' (redirected from 'https://localhost:3000/logout') from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> > jquery.min.js:2

> > GET https://xxxxxx.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout?id_token_hint=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F net::ERR_FAILED

I then tried this ajax call:

```js
if (this.currSeconds >= 5 && this.authenticated === true) {
  // this.logoutOIDC
  $.ajax({
    url: 'logout',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:3000/',
    },
    type: 'dataType',
    /* etc */
    success: function(jsondata) {
      console.log(jsondata)
    },
  })
}
```

This produces the same errors.

Of course, "$('#auth-logout-form').trigger('submit')" works great, but it does not seem like the proper approach, and I believe this leaves logout functionality too easily disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from Okta was to go ahead and use $('#auth-logout-form').trigger('submit') if I was going to use the middleware. There may be another way, but this method was suitable under the circumstances.